# How does one find missing fonts using Inkscape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, font-identification, inkscape

I have an Adobe Illustrator file that I am opening with Inkscape. Everything works great except some of the text is all screwed up because I don't have all of the appropriate fonts available on my computer. So, my question is... is there any way to find out which fonts in particular I am missing for this specific file?

Comment: This happens to me even with non-Illustrator files: with Inkscape files created on a different computer.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum, I don't see a Type menu... are you referring to Inkscape?

Comment: oops, sorry, my bad. Reading comprehension fail. :) I thought you were using Illustrator.

Comment: @coffee-grinder, yep I understand... I just specified that the file type was Illustrator in case there was some way to extract the meta data from the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only trick I know of is to start editing the text itself; the text toolbar will show you the name of the font, and give you a little '!' icon to show you the font is not installed. As for searching for a bunch of missing fonts *en masse*, I don't know of any technique. I bet someone could write a script for that though!

Comment: I think you solved mine. All I needed was the name of the font. I can simply search online then download and add it to Windows font directory. Thanks @ Paul d'Aoust

Answer (score 2):

Look at ai file in text editor, search for “Font” phrase. If fonts are not converted to outlines and your ai file contains xmp meta or is not compressed, you should be able to read font names directly. One could even do a simple script to simply list used fonts. Also it may be a nice idea for python extension for Inkscape. Try to throw that idea on dev list.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible yet, and I don't think this should be an extension. It's an essential core feature. The way Scribus does it is telling user about missing fonts upon loading a document and suggesting to replace those missing fonts with some of the available ones.

If you have time, please check the bug tracker for an existing report on that, and if there isn't one, please file it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I just learned [Inkscape has a very useful extension called Replace Font](https://askubuntu.com/a/660130/308825), which is found under Extensions --> Text. The extension enables you to search the open document and find and/or replace its fonts, or list all fonts used in it.